# Does ultraviolet behavior of quantum Yang – Mills theory with no instability indicates single particle theory that connects gravity with QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, gravity

The ultraviolet behavior of quantum Yang – Mills theory possess no instability as the separation between physical gluons becomes exceedingly smaller & smaller with increase in energy. Ultimately, at quantum length, in the limit of approaching the origin of field space, the dynamical variables, becomes so infinitesimal in magnitude that they effectively represent a single physical gluon G . At Gribov horizon, application of Gauss Divergence theorem to this single physical gluon G leads to singularities of color-Coulomb potential spread all over a spherical surface β at quantum length of physical gluon.
After acquiring additional degree of freedom in the form of free color-Coulomb potential at Gribov horizon, the gluon ‘G’ has the aforesaid spherical system β firmly attached to it. At Gribov horizon, the uncertainty principle forbids this spherical system β, of constant radius (h’/8π), to undergo any Lorentz – Fitzgerald contraction in laboratory inertial frame and rather, demands the motion of gluon ‘G’ to instantaneously drop to zero speed in the laboratory inertial reference frame. This sudden deceleration in the speed of gluon ‘G’ at Gribov horizon assigns an inertial mass to gluon ‘G’ in accordance with General Relativity theory. This inertial mass of gluon ‘G’ produces gravitational effect in its surroundings because of equivalence between inertial mass & gravitational mass in General Relativity theory.
For further details, please click the following link.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346075636_Mathematical_Connection_between_Gravity_and_Standard_Model